# "Everyday" as an adverb

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

According to OED, the adjective *everyday*, meaning ‘happening or used every day’ or ‘commonplace’ (everyday chores), is written as one word, whereas the adverb meaning ‘each day, daily’ (I get up at six every day) is written as two.

However, we can often see *everyday* used as an adverb but written as one word, even in authoritative publications. For example, I have read the following on Forbes.com: "Maybe you go to the same pizzeria **everyday**..." (https://www.forbes.com/pictures/efkk45khfk/dont-get-stuck-in-a-routine/#27918af73775).

Bon Jovi has a song called "Everyday" (always written as one word) but he sings "I'm gonna live my life **every day**"...

So, is this really a mistake to write the adverb as one word?

Comment: Forbes seems to have missed that! It should be, IMO, *every day.*

Comment: Bon Jovi lives his **everyday** life every day.

Comment: "Every day" when written as two words is not an adverb, but a noun phrase with the noun "day" as head and the determinative "every" as determiner. It usually functions as a temporal adjunct, as in "I go there every day".

Comment: How do you know Bon Jovi sings it as *everyday*? Random lyrics websites don't count. You should listen to the song and hear for yourself. (I did, and he really doesn't.) There's a difference in pronunciation between the two, even if native speakers sometimes fail at *spelling it out*.

Comment: @userr2684291 When I listen to the song, everything is OK. But when I see the song title, I'm confused. Check the track listing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_(Bon_Jovi_album)#Track_listing.
I mean, I don't have questions about the pronunciation, the singing is great. But why do they use "everyday" instead of "every day" as a song title?

Comment: That question is really out of the scope of ELL.SE. You might want to check out this article on [*artistic license*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license).

Comment: Why isn't it an "allday sucker"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pz3rrESMnzI

Comment: @Enguroo: There's far from perfect consistency in the way such compounds are formed. Sometimes you will find the pieces stuck together as a single "word", sometimes they will be joined by a hyphen, and sometimes they will be presented as separate "words".  Writing and typography are merely representations of language. They are not the thing itself. Writing and language are like liquids with different melting and freezing temperatures.

Comment: Forbes isn't entirely authoritative, at least not on grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example, "*Maybe you go to the same pizzeria <s>everyday</s>...*" is incorrect, and any editor would correct that to "***every day***".

Your understanding is correct, and better than the large number of native speakers who make this everyday mistake every day.

Comment: "and any editor would correct that to "every day"." Putting the word "competent" before "editor" would make that more accurate, as would replacing "would" with "should".